# Suggestions: improve storage of input changes

Tags: javascript

I have developed a very simple script to detect changes in an input field. I want to use the script to detect and analyse if and how the numbers in an formfield have been changed.

At the moment, the input value is stored whenever a single number is changed. Does anyone know if it is possible to change the code in a way that the input value is stored not after every change in a single value but after  the whole number or parts of the whole number have been changed?

F.e. user writes value 300 in the input field.
code below: `["3","30","300"]`
what I want: `["300"]`

```js
var text;
var input = [];

$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#form_1').on('input', function() {
    text = $('#form_1').val();
    $('#show').html(text);
    input.push(text);
    console.log(text);
    console.log(input);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="form_1">

<p> Value in input field:<span id='show'></span></p>
```

Comment: You can't know in advance how many numbers will be written by user, so unless you change the event you detect (for example mouseout or something not related to input) it's really difficult I think

Comment: Thank you. I already assumed that this might be quite difficult. Maybe, I should really think about another event. mouseout is a seems to be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I think would be to only save the input if the user doesn't enter any further numbers for e.g. a second:

```js
var text;
var input = [];
var timeout;

$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#form_1').on('input', function() {
    text = $('#form_1').val();
    $('#show').html(text);
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      if ($('#form_1').val() == text) {
        input.push(text);
      }
      console.log($('#form_1').val() == text, $('#form_1').val(), text)
    }, 1000)
  })
  $('#show').on("click", function() {
    console.log(input);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="form_1">

<p> Value in input field: <span id='show'></span></p>
```

Click on `#show` to get the array printed !

Comment: Thank you very much. That really seems to be the perfect solution for my problem!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the onblur event, which triggers when the user clicks outside the input field or it otherwise loses focus.

Or you could set a timeout, and only store the input when the user has not made any changes for e.g. a second